# How to search a git repository history to find a merge error?

Tags: git, merge

At some point in our past  branches of development in git were merged.  However, the wrong merge decision was made and therefore some code didn't make it into master branch that we expected would be there.  (There were multiple merges of different branches before a final merge to a master branch.  So the branching and merging history was fairly complex.)

Is there an easy way to search a git repository to determine on which merge the "wrong" decision was made on?

(I already know the answer for this particular case, but the process of finding it was a bit tedious.)

EDIT:  The reason git blame proved inadequate is that the line was touched in a commit sometime after the merge error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know a line in a file that was modified by the git branch merge, you can do 'git blame file.txt' and determine the commit hash number and commit author of the line in the file.  Then you can go through the git log and pull up the exact commit associated with the bad branch merge.

EDIT:
In response to the author's comments, if you're looking for the disappearance of a certain line then 'git diff' combined with grep and binary search could be what you want.  let's say you have commit numbers 0,1,2,3,4,5,6.  You know that the line existed in revision 0, but disappeared in revision 6.  Use 'git diff' plus grep to search for the disappearance.

```
git diff 0 6 | grep '- line I care about'
```

The first iteration, you'll see the line you care about disappearing.  Then you cut the revision number in half and try again

```
git diff 0 3 | grep '- line I care about'
```

If the grep still shows the line disappearing ( with the '-' sign), then you know that the line disappeared in revision 0 to 3.  If the grep *doesn't* show the line disappearing, then the line disappeared in revisions 4-6.

Keep cutting the revisions in half until you find the culprit.

Comment: The problem was that the line was touched sometime after the "merge error".  I knew when the patch was introduced but couldn't easily tell when it first dropped out.

Comment: Rather then git diff and search, use the options that git log provides. Specifically, try `git log <HERE>..<THERE> -S"line I care about" --diff-filter=M`

Comment: The process you describe is what git bisect does. However, you don't have to count hashes. While your 0-6, 0-3/4-6, etc. pattern is clear and understandable, you can't use commit numbers. You have to use commit hashes and that is not clear. git bisect is your friend.

Answer (score 10):

Without more details I can only hint at **possible** solutions. If you know the file or line affected, you can try either [git-blame](http://git.or.cz/man/git-blame) (`git blame *file*`, or `git blame *revision* *file*`), or you can try so called '**pickaxe** search' with [git-log](http://git.or.cz/man/git-log), i.e. `git log -S'*line*` trying to find revision which introduced given line, or deleted given line. You can find and examine all merges, for example via `git log -p -m --grep=Merge`, and examine how they relate to their parents (`-m` show diffs to all parents; alternatively `-c` shows combined diff but doesn't show trivial merge changes, i.e. if one side was taken).

Answer (score 9):

Can [git-bisect](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html) help in your case?

Answer (score 9):

Git log has powerful searching options. Since there's the indication you might know a chunk of code that disappeared, you can search for that string of code

`git log <HERE>..<THERE> -S"line I care about" --diff-filter=M`

Will search from HERE to THERE for the string after `-S` and only where the line was modified (added or removed)

You can achieve even more precision in your search if you use -G instead of -S. -G provides regular expression searching instead of string literal searching with -S.

Comment: This is AWESOME! I didn't not know about this. Thank you!

Comment: This can be very hand with -p option to show patches rather than commit summaries. So you can actually see the changes for the commits that match.

Comment: Note that you must add option `-c` for this to work properly. Otherwise `git log` will skip changes introduced by merge commits.

Answer (score 0):

For others looking for a simpler solution, fire up `gitk` (or from Git GUI go to Repository > Visualise *X* History) and use its find tool.