# Detect a specific change happened in a list of commits

Tags: git

How do I can get in which commit did a change happen?

I have 67 commits in a pull request. There's a mistake in the final diff with code that should be there and is being removed. How do I solve such thing? How do I know in which commit is that piece of code that is changing the final merge diff?

Comment: This question was already answered:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554660/how-to-search-a-git-repository-history-to-find-a-merge-error

Comment: @gview If it has, it's not that question. That is about what to do after the merge, not during the pull request.

Comment: Your question is which commit lost you a "piece of code".  Isolate a line that is missing from the piece, and use git log <HERE>..<THERE> -S"line I care about" --diff-filter=M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code is already commited you can use `git blame` to find what happened [6.5 Git Tools - track down a bug in your code and want to know when it was introduced and why](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git#File-Annotation).

If the code is on Github you can simply use the Blame button when looking at the relevant file. I use this method a lot for looking at git & msysgit itself (to know who's toes I might be stepping on ;-).

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. The blame system. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what that missing piece of code is you could do:

```
git log -p
```

and then search through for that missing piece of code and which commit removes it.

Comment: -p is for generating a patch. I'm not trying to make a patch, yet. I'm trying to find in which commit did those changes happened.

Comment: Yes, the patches are "per commit", so you could search through the output until you find the specific piece of code and in the header section of that piece will be the commit id.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering on file path also gets you a quick answer, often:

`git log --pretty=oneline -- src/main/java/com/brunoais/Foo.java`

That'll display only the commits affecting the file `src/main/java/com/brunoais/Foo.java`, with comments in the right-hand column of the output.

Here's the breakdown.

- The `--` part is the path specification prefix. It can be applied to other git commands, not just git-log. (It's often optional; git only needs `--` if there's ambiguity, e.g., if the file path happens to be the same as a branch name.)
- The `--pretty=oneline` part makes the output concise.